# Reading OneDrive files to R

Tags: r, csv, dropbox, onedrive

When I read in csv files from Dropbox into `R`, I right-click the file and click `share Dropbox link`. I then have a URL something like:

`https://www.dropbox.com/blahhhhhhhhhh.csv?dl=0`

So I change it to:
`read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/blahhhhhhhhhh.csv?dl=0", ...)` and it works without the need to use any packages etc.

Is there a way to read files from OneDrive in a similar manner?

`https://onedrive.live.com/blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhccsv`

As when I try to read it into `R` it doesn't give me the data frame I'm expecting from the file.

Comment: Try `curl` from the **curl** package.

Comment: Is there a way without using any packages?

Comment: Sure but why reinvent what someone has taken the time to do so well?  Look at the source code used in that package.  Also I don't even know if `curl` will work as this question isn't reproducible.

Comment: Be aware that you manually have to change the link generated with the right-click. The “redirect” - part in the url has to be changed to “download”. Like so: 

original link: "onedrive.live.com/redirect?resid=20f8f50d960ce4e4!151&authkey=xxxxxxxx&ithint=file%2ccsv” 
to 
"onedrive.live.com/download?resid=20f8f50d960ce4e4!151&authkey=xxxxxxxx&ithint=file%2ccsv”.

Answer (score 4):

I tested this with public OneDrive link:

- download the file
- get the URL in download page (Ctrl+J in Chrome):

[[image]]

- paste the URL in read.csv("url...")

This works for me even when the public link changes.

Answer (score 2):

OneFlow gave me "embed" in the URL, so I changed it to "download" and got the resul

Answer (score 2):

None of those answers work for me, but I found an alternative solution that works.

- Find the file in OneDrive online using Chrome.
- Share it to anyone with the link.
- Right click the … and select “download”.
- Let the file download.
- Press Ctrl + J to open the Downloads page in Chrome.
- Find the link on that page for the file.

Use the following code to download the file.

```r
read_url_csv <- function(url, ...){
  tmpFile <- tempfile()
  download.file(url, destfile = tmpFile)
  url_csv <- readr::read_csv(tmpFile, ...)
  return(url_csv)
}
onedrive_url <- "INSERT LINK COPIED ABOVE"
csv <- read_url_csv(onedrive)
```

Comment: This solution will not work if you are using OneDrive for Business and your admin has disabled the use of public file sharing via links.

Answer (score 0):

Reddit users [recommend syncing One Drive files locally and reading the local files](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/9m1pfu/how_to_read_onedrive_excel_documents_into_r/).

That worked for me.

1. Have the person(s) who manage the shared location share the folder
   location  with you. (It's possible sharing a file could work, but I
   haven't explored that. Folder location worked for me when testing,
   so that's what I recommend).
2. Open the shared folder in One Drive
3. Click "Sync"

You should now have the a local copy of those files stored on your PC and syncing online (just like Dropbox). You files will probably found in a sub-folder of this location:

C:\Users[Your user name]\

[image: One Drive Share and Sync buttons]

Comment: this answer isn't machine reading friendly, and so it isn't part of FAIR data protocols.