# Unable to source file even after I specify path for the source in R

Tags: r, parsing, directory, path

I am trying to read a csv file and source file, both located in the same folder.

```
    myData = read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\Karen\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DB\\HtWt.csv") #CSV

    source("C:\\Users\\Karen\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DB\\Jags.R") #source file
```

While the CSV file is reading just fine, the source file says `Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the connection`

I even set the working directory to the DB folder but no luck.

Comment: Are you using RStudio? Try typing `source("C:\\Users\\Karen\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DB\\ ` and then press the `Tab` key. A list of files should appear, see if the file you want is suggested.

Comment: I can select the file but no luck. Same error

Comment: Ohh - this may be an issue with reading from OneDrive. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579782/reading-onedrive-files-to-r

Comment: I moved it to dropbox like folder. But again same problem.

Comment: The answers to that question suggest you need to download the file.

Comment: R likes to work locally, like @BrianStamper said, download to local drive and have another go :)