# Access Excel and CSV Data from OneDrive via R

Tags: r, sharepoint, onedrive

I am trying to Access some Excel and CSV files stored on both a corporate One Drive and Corporate Sharepoint via readXL - the raw data is stored there everyday and I need to import and manipulate it.
None of the posts seems to supply and answer.
I have tried downloading the file (get a 403 Error), using readXL to open the file and ReadCSV code.
Every link I try seems to be can't find file.
Any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29579782/3358272, https://richardsprague.com/post/2019/09/20/r-tude-read-onedrive-excel-files/, and https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/9m1pfu/how_to_read_onedrive_excel_documents_into_r/. The common themes I've found, one of: (1) get the current URL from the onedrive interface and use that directly; (2) mount as a drive letter and access as if local; or (3) just download it manually. I'm guessing you want something automated, perhaps `rvest` allows you to navigate through authentication to locate the file? (I've not tried, I do not use onedrive.)

Comment: Thanks but had tried all of this with no success.

Comment: You've mounted onedrive as a local drive letter and could not read even that in R? If that's the case, then please [edit] your question and add the code you used to try to read the "local" (drive-letter mounted) file: if you cannot read a "local" file, then it might be: (1) a mistake or typo in your code; (2) an antivirus problem, blocking R from local file access; or (3) your R is fundamentally broken (if this latter, then you'll need to completely uninstall R and your personally library, then reinstall).

Comment: Not allowed to Map onedrive or sharepoint due to IT constraints. Code am using is Marex_EoD <- read_excel('//xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx_UK/Documents/PRICES FOR SCRAPING/XXXX/XXXX EoD Curve - 17.Jul.2020.xlsx',col_types  all) - I did re-install R so that is why i need to find the way you can read sharepoint like other file servers

Comment: I'm inferring `readxl::read_excel`, in which case it might be informative to pay attention to the error: `\`path\` does not exist`, because `readxl` requires local files only. When you copy the link from a browser window, if you use `download.file(myurl, "somedest.xlsx", mode="wb")`, does it work?