# Reading Onedrive file to R

Tags: r, onedrive

This question is VERY similar to this one:  [Reading OneDrive files to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579782/reading-onedrive-files-to-r)

But with a slight twist:

I have an R script that opens a connection to a database.  This is roughly that code (names changed to protect the innocent):

```
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", classPath="C:/Users/JohnDoe/OneDrive - Job Corporation/Documents/Data/jar files/ojdbc8.jar")  
jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=place.company.com)(PORT=1234))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ghjed)))", "abc_thing_prod_ro4", "AKabc$VxqcasdfdsTDYjZsadfcdy-pxEUW")
```

As you can see, in that first line I link to the location of a ".jar" file that the code needs.  Its already in my OneDrive, and because my onedrive is locally mapped to me, this code works great and opens a connection.

The problem is I need to be able to share this R code with other people, and have the code still work when run on their computer. (and really, ultimately, all this R code is actually run inside of a powerBI file).  So in other words, I think I'd like to have a line of code that would read in/download the file from OneDrive so it could be run on other computers.

In [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680143/4309821) to that other question, it looks like it would do roughly that.  It looks like his answer would download a csv that was on onedrive and had been linked to, but the problem one commenter pointed out was that "*if you are using OneDrive for Business and your admin has disabled the use of public file sharing via links*" it will not work.  Well, thats exactly my case.

That being said the only people who'd be running this code are within my organization and ARE allowed to download from onedrive links I share.  When I just tried to run the solutions code as-is I get an error of "http status was '403 forbidden'

Am I just plain out of luck?  Is there a way to get R to read from a onedrive link (when run on other computers) if our admin doesnt like public link sharing?

**Update to further clarify (hopefully)**

So to reiterate, when my colleague and I share files in R by saving them to a Onedrive location we can both access, the R files will have lines of code that point to Onedrive locations (that we should be able to both access), something like this:

```
    source("C:/Users/123456/OneDrive - Lifespan Corporation/PowerBI/Test_Auto.R")
```

Problem is, when I look at that file, it looks like this to me:
[image]

I.e. the filepath is different.  So... even though I can access those files in onedrive, if I try to run that line of code in R, it fails and I get this:

[image]

So to reiterate my question:

Is there a way in R to either write that Onedrive filepath or do something where no matter what user is trying to run the code, it'll allow access.

I tried to use the 'web' address of the file like this:

```
source("https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/123456_company_org/Documents/PowerBI/Test_Auto.R")
```

And got a similar error.  But if I paste that line into my browser it'll download the file, so I definitely have access.

Comment: Do you have a limited/known set of users who need this to work for them? One option would be to share the OneDrive folder in question with those users, and have them sync it so that it's available via a local drive path, i.e. `C:/Users/Mako/OneDrive/file.jar`. And then search for/construct the path in your script `sprintf('C:/Users/%s/OneDrive/file.jar', shell('whoami'))`. I don't know if that's really a best practice, but it might work

Comment: Its only two of us for the foreseeable future and we both have it synced locally so I'm following all of that, but I'm lost on that last sprintf command.  Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Generally when you sync a OneDrive folder, you'll get a user specific path, so even if I were to sync a folder stored on your OneDrive, I'd get a path like `C:/Users/Mako/OneDrive/Joe's Folder`. So my point with `sprintf` is that to use that path on both machines, the path needs to be dynamic to the user.  `sprintf('C:/Users/%s/OneDrive/file.jar', Sys.info()[["user"]])` would be a better way to construct it than my initial example with `shell`.

Comment: But then again, if it's just you and one other person, you could just include the direct path based on each users system, and then check each path with `file.exists` to determine which path to use.

Comment: That was perfect!  Didnt realize how easy that would be!  Would you like to provide it as an "answer" so i can mark it solved and give you the bounty etc?

Comment: Sure, I'll write a little expanded answer. Glad it solved your issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our conversion in the comments:

In your local environment you have a folder like this:

```
C:/Users/Mako/OneDrive/file.jar
```

And if you share that folder with a collaborator and they sync it in their local environment, they'll have a path like this:

```
C:/Users/OtherUser/OneDrive/file.jar
```

So when `OtherUser` tries to access the path `C:/Users/Mako/OneDrive/file.jar`, they'll get the "No such file or directory" error.

We can fix this if we either validate the path first based on a known local environment path for each user, or we can dynamically construct the path if it conforms to a general structure.

Dynamically, we can use a function like `sprintf()` to construct a path based on the user:

```
sprintf('C:/Users/%s/OneDrive/file.jar', Sys.info()[["user"]])
  
[1] "C:/Users/Mako/OneDrive/file.jar"
```

Or statically we can specify two paths:

```
path1 <- 'C:/Users/Mako/OneDrive/file.jar'
path2 <- 'C:/Users/OtherUser/OneDrive/file.jar'
```

And then check for a valid path:

```
if (file.exists(path1)) {
  path <- path1
} else if (file.exists(path2)) {
  path <- path2
} else {
  print("Error, no valid path found")
}
```

Comment: It wont let me give the bounty for a day, will do tomorrow